# Negation rules in natural deduction

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, natural-deduction

There are various treatments of using negation in natural deduction for classical logic.

Let me quote bits of it:

$$\frac{}{\top}\top I$$

$$\frac{\bot}{A}\bot E\quad ex\ falso\ quodlibet$$

$$\frac{A\rightarrow\bot}{\neg A}\neg I$$

$$\frac{}{A\vee \neg A}tertium\ non\ datur$$

$$\frac{A\quad \neg A}{\bot}law\ of\ contradiction$$

$$\frac{A}{\neg\neg A}double\ negation\ 1$$

$$\frac{\neg\neg A}{A}double\ negation\ 2$$

$$\frac{\begin{equation}\begin{array}{c}{[\neg A]\\ \vdots\\ \bot}\end{array}\end{equation}}{A}indirect\ proof$$

What is a standard way of building this, what are the axioms and how are the other rules are proved?

You might answer this by referring to some reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only true "negation rule" needed is reductio ad absurdum aka proof by contradiction:

$$\dfrac{\begin{equation}\begin{array}{c}{[\neg A]\\ \vdots\\ \bot}\end{array}\end{equation}}{A}\bot$$

It is important to note that RAA is not an instance of negation introduction (see  below) but actually a separate rule.

$\neg A$ can be defined as syntactic sugar for what is actually $A \to \bot$, and $\top$ as $\neg \bot$ and hence $\bot \to \bot$. There is no deduction rule needed for switching between the two, they are treated as literally same formula that just looks different:

$$\neg A  \quad = \quad A \to \bot$$
$$\top \quad =  \quad\neg \bot \quad = \quad \bot \to \bot$$

Negation introduction and elimination is then a special case of implication introduction and elimination (negation elimination is what you call law of contradiction, and implication elimination is also known as modus ponens):

$$\frac{\begin{equation}\begin{array}{c}{[A]\\ \vdots\\ \bot}\end{array}\end{equation}}{\neg A}\neg I
\quad = \quad 
\frac{\begin{equation}\begin{array}{c}{[A]\\ \vdots\\ \bot}\end{array}\end{equation}}{A \to \bot}\to I 
$$

$$$$

$$\frac{A\quad \neg A}{\bot}\neg E
\quad = \quad
\frac{A\quad A \to \bot}{\bot}\to E
$$
EFQL is just RAA with no assumption discharged (see the comments for a discussion on the difference between the two):

$$\frac{\bot}{A}\text{EFQL}
\quad \rightsquigarrow \quad
\frac{\bot}{A}\bot
$$

The other rules can then be derived from these primitive rules:

For double negation,

$$\dfrac{A}{\neg\neg A}\neg \neg I
\quad \rightsquigarrow \quad
\dfrac{\dfrac{[\neg A]^1 \quad A}{\bot}\neg E}{\neg \neg A}\neg I^1
\quad = \quad
\dfrac{\dfrac{[A \to \bot]^1 \quad A}{\bot}\to E}{(A \to \bot) \to \bot}\to I^1
$$

and

$$\dfrac{\neg \neg A}{A}\neg \neg E
\quad \rightsquigarrow \quad
\dfrac{\dfrac{\neg \neg A \quad [\neg A]^1}{\bot}\neg E}{A}\bot^1
\quad = \quad
\dfrac{\dfrac{(A \to \bot) \to \bot \quad [A \to \bot]^1}{\bot}\to E}{A}\bot^1
$$

For the axioms,

$$\dfrac{}{\top}\top I 
\quad = \quad
\dfrac{}{\neg \bot}\top I
\quad \rightsquigarrow \quad
\dfrac{[\bot]^1}{\neg \bot}\neg I
\quad = \quad
\dfrac{[\bot]^1}{\bot \to \bot}\to I^1
$$

and finally, $$
\dfrac{}{A\vee \neg A}\text{TND}
\quad \rightsquigarrow \quad
$$

see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsQ9o.png); their $(* B)$ is our $* E$  (eliminiation) and $(* E)$ is $* I$ (introduction).

So natural deduction doesn't need axiom as primitives: Everything can be derived from the basic set of inference rules $\{\land I, \land E, \lor I, \lor E, \to I, \to E, \bot\}$.

Comment: Thanks indeed. The only thing I cannot grasp is how I imagined Reduction ad Absurdum as Ex Falso Quodlibet. Could you elaborate or give a reference?

Comment: For rules that allow to discharge assumptions, it is allowed to not actually discharge all occurrences of the assumption, and even to not have the assumption present in the derivation at all. RAA would allow us to discharge assumptions of the form $\neg A$ that led to $\bot$, but we are also allowed to use the rule if we do not have such an assumption. This application then coincides with EFQL.

Comment: See e.g. D. van Dalen *Logic and Structure* p. 34: "W.r.t. the cancellation of hypotheses, we note that one does not necessarily cancel all occurrences of such a proposition \psi. [...] Furthermore, one may apply (-> I) [and RAA] if there is no hypothesis available for cancellation."

Comment: OK but how A comes into the picture then?

Comment: It's the conclusion we'd also get if we had the assumption $\neg A$. Since we could have started off with any negative formula except we don't need it, the conclusion can be an arbitrary formula $A$.

Comment: EFQL has the form of the $\bot$ rule without the $[\neg A] \ldots$ part, and we don't need the $[\neg A] \ldots$ to be there to call it $\bot$. So EFQL is just a special case of RAA.

Comment: They are actually quite distinct.  For instance EFQL is Intuitionistically valid, where as ordinary RAA is not.

Comment: @Sure; I left that detail out because the OP specifically asked about classical logic. But I find it not too unreasonable to treat the two in a unified form; after all, a complete proof system for IL can be obtained from that for CL *just* by modifying the $\bot$ rule such that no assumption may be discharged, and one may call these two variants of the "contradiction rule" $\bot_c$ and $\bot_i$ respectively, as done source of the TND derivation.

Comment: @Graham Kemp But agreed, the equality sign between the two was somewhat misleading; I changed it.

Comment: @NatalieClarius one more question: why is Reduction Ad Absurdum is not an instance of negation introduction? It seems so.

Comment: @Gergley Because we are removing a negation, not introducing one. Negation introduction allows us to go from $A$ to $A \to falsum$, but there is no way to instantiate these formulas such that we start with some $A \to falsum$ and end up with just $A$.